# converting Multiple pages pdfs into PNG in R

Tags: r, loops

The code can convert multiple-pages-pdf file into septate identical page

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_convert("Merit List.pdf", format = "png", pages = NULL, filenames = NULL, dpi = 300, opw = "", upw = "", verbose = TRUE)
```

What I need is to convert all pages of multiple pdf in their specific directories, the list is just an example I have a directory containing all pdfs having images

```
list <- c("pdf/data/Merit List.pdf", 
          "pdf/data/New/Merit List.pdf")
```

Tried to convert with the following code but it failed, I guess need a loop or function as far searched on web but I'm not expert in R

```
library(pdftools)
    pdf_convert(list, format = "png", pages = NULL, filenames = NULL, dpi = 300, opw = "", upw = "", verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: [magick](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) is handy for this sort of thing; all you really need is `image_read` and `image_write` unless there's something particularly weird. Or use imagemagick directly from the command line, if you prefer.

Comment: yap i tried to do with magick but could not do for multiple files and yap i managed command line with pdftocairo but its hard to do for hundred and thousands files :-( so just tring to figure out R way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing it using :-

```
library(pdftools)
sapply(list, function(x)
  pdf_convert(x, format = "png", pages = NULL, filenames = NULL, dpi = 300, opw = "", upw = "", verbose = TRUE))
```

It worked for me.

Comment: yap it is showing the file is being converted but not saving converted image and placing into the folder :-(

Comment: I'm surprised where converted PNG files go??? as they are supposed to be in folders "pdf/data" and "pdf/data/new"

Comment: Oh its working but half i just reopened R... its saving all PNGs in working directory/main directory not into sub directories :-( i want all converted PNGs to be placed where pdf is!! any suggestion ?

Comment: @Janjua, yes all the files will be saved in working directory. Can't you make the directory where you want files to get saved as working directory? This should solve your problem.

Comment: well i have a structured data with unique directories and sub directories its important that all the converted images must be in those specific directories where the original PDF is located any suggestion

Comment: You can use `filenames` argument of `pdf_convert`. It'll create .png files with specific name in a specific folder.

Comment: yap i'm trying to find some help

Comment: @sm925 is it possible to collage all pages of PDfs into single page ? or all pages into a single jpg/png ? I don't want 1 image per page, I want collage of the images in the PDF into 1

Comment: Any solution for the following issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307799/how-to-get-full-ggplot-while-converting-to-png-from-pdf-using-pdftools-in-r

Answer (score 3):

Try this It work for me

```r
library(pdftools)
directory<-"pdf/data"
file.list <- paste(directory, "/",list.files(directory, pattern = "*.pdf"), sep = "")
lapply(file.list, FUN = function(files) {pdf_convert(files, format = "png",dpi = 300,pages =NULL,filenames =)})
```

Comment: Any solution for the following issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307799/how-to-get-full-ggplot-while-converting-to-png-from-pdf-using-pdftools-in-r